# Possible bug in jQuery 1.6 - $(...).attr("checked") is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.6

I have two radio buttons on my form and up until I started using jQuery 1.6 the following code worked fine:

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="test"/>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="test"/>
<input type="button" onclick="testcheck()" value="Test"/>
<script>
function testcheck()
{
    if (jQuery("#radio1").attr("checked"))
        alert("first button checked");
    else if (jQuery("#radio2").attr("checked"))
        alert("second button checked");
    else
        alert("none checked")      
}
</script>
```

Once I start using jQuery 1.6, it always shows "none checked" because `jQuery(radiobutton).attr("checked")` is always empty.

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Eqpu/7/), and change jQuery version between 1.5.2 and 1.6 to see what I mean.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at this question: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Try this for your code instead:

```
function testcheck()
{
    if (jQuery("#radio1").prop("checked"))
        alert("first button checked");
    else if (jQuery("#radio2").prop("checked"))
        alert("second button checked");
    else
        alert("none checked")      
}
```

Also in the newest [jQuery 1.6.1](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/10/jquery-1-6-1-rc-1-released/) they fixed some of the 1.6 `attr` problems

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug but a change:

http://christierney.com/2011/05/06/understanding-jquery-1-6s-dom-attribute-and-properties/

Also, as mentioned by @Neal they have worked on this a bit in the latest [1.6.1 release candidate](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/10/jquery-1-6-1-rc-1-released/).

From the RC link:

> Upgrading From 1.5.2 to 1.6.1 - With the
>   introduction of the new .prop() method
>   and the changes to the .attr() method,
>   jQuery 1.6 sparked a discussion about
>   the difference between attributes and
>   properties and how they relate to each
>   other. It also came with some
>   backwards compatibility issues that
>   have been fixed in 1.6.1. When
>   updating from 1.5.2 to 1.6.1, you
>   should not have to change any code.

There's a lot more explanation there but you might be able to skip to 1.6.1 and be fine...

**EDIT - Added below on 5/16/11**

John Resig just weighed in on the changes made around this and why....  Good read....

http://ejohn.org/blog/jquery-16-and-attr/

Comment: Thank you for using my source?

Comment: @Neal - I wanted to attribute you linking to it first.  Isn't it better to reference you instead of just writing what I did without mentioning that you already did....?  Certainly meant no disrepect. :-)

Comment: lol ook. just might be better suited as a comment, rather than a fully `new` answer :-p

Comment: @Neal - I already had answered and added to my answer with the quote to let @Andrey know he might be able to skip right to the RC to fix his issue. Your answer didn't state that.... :-) I did +1 you also. :-)

Comment: @Neal - Yes. "Fixed some of the 1.6 attr problems." But what & more specifically the post states you can go to 1.6.1 from 1.5.2 to help avoid the issues.  I wanted to point this out to @Andrey and anyone else since it is directly tied to solving his issue.

Answer (score 3):

I've been seeing this too.  The other answers have some insights as to why this is, and when it'll be reverted (only for getters?); in the meantime, I've been using

```
$('#thingy').is(':checked');
```

as a cross-version workaround.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain the change between versions, but there is a selector specifically looking for checked - http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can hack it this way: `jQuery("input[name='test']:checked")`

The demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/8Eqpu/15/

Answer (score 0):

`.attr()` and `.data()` have changed dramatically in jQuery 1.6.

It's better explained on this article:

[Upgrading to jQuery 1.6: Problems you may face](http://edgarinvillegas.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/upgrading-to-jquery-1-6-troubleshooting/)

Hope this helps. Cheers