# JQuery Radio button not being selected in IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-6

I have the following code

```
<input type="radio" name="HotelSearch_Measure" value="Miles">
<input type="radio" name="HotelSearch_Measure" value="KM">
```

However when I use the following it works in IE9/Chrome/Firefox but not in IE6

```
jQuery("input[value='Miles'").attr("checked", true);
```

I've tried searching with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: typo ? jQuery("input[value='Miles']").attr("checked", true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery < 1.6
do this:

```
jQuery("input[value='Miles']").attr("checked", 'checked');
```

If you are using jQuery  1.6+:

```
jQuery("input[value='Miles']").prop("checked", true);
```

See this question: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) and [Possible bug in jQuery 1.6 - $(...).attr("checked") is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969598/possible-bug-in-jquery-1-6-attrchecked-is-not-working) for references why.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will work for IE6 and for the other browsers also

```
jQuery("input[value='Miles']").attr("checked", "checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided your typo (`jQuery("input[value='Miles']").attr("checked", true);`) occurred when typing your question, and isn't present in your live code, what you have is the **correct** way to do it, prior to jQuery 1.6.0.

With the new version however, the new method [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) should be used:

```
jQuery("input[value='Miles']").prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery 1.6+ uses [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) like this:

```
jQuery('input[value="Miles"]').prop("checked", true);
```